# How to divide count-values of two different tables?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I work with Power Bi and my initial datasets look like the following:

| *table 1* |  |  | *table 2* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **user** |  |  | **user** |
| a |  |  | a |
| a |  |  | c |
| b |  |  | b |
| a |  |  | a |
| b |  |  | b |
| a |  |  | a |
|  |  |  | a |
|  |  |  | a |
|  |  |  | b |
|  |  |  | e |

I have two different tables. Each table has a column user.

Here I would like to get the ratio of table1 to table2 per user (count).
That means I want to calculate the frequency of how often a user appears first:

***table 1:***

count user a: 4

count user b: 2

***table 2:***

count user a: 5

count user b: 3

count user c: 1

count user e: 1

And finally i just want to calculate the ratio of table 1 and table 2 for the values ​​that occur in table 1:

user a: 4/5 = 0,8

user b: 2/3 = 0,66

How to approach in DAX? I have no clue tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `Many-to-many` relationship between those two tables, based on the *user* column, you can then create the following `measure`:

`Ratio = COUNTROWS('table 1')/COUNTROWS('table 2')`

formatted as *percentage*, which can be placed in a simple Table visual alongside the *user* field from *table 1*.